# How can i design proper java swing mvc design - is this mvc design example right?

Tags: java

I designed controller class in mvc like below.

```
public class ControllerMr implements Observer {

ModelMr modelmr = new ModelMr();
PanelMr vpanelmr= new PanelMr();

public ControllerMr() {
    this.modelmr.registerObserver(this);
    this.vpanelmr.registerObserver(this);
}
```

when i instantiate controller class, i create model and view class. my view here is swing panel. for example i add this panel to tab or frame in another view.

i connect my controller to model and view with the help of observer pattern. You see in the constructor, i register my controller to the model and view. so there is indirect connection with observer pattern, and concurrency management will be more easy.

is this design true , if it is wrong, should i set my view and model outer of controller class like below

```
ControllerMr controllermr= new ControllerMr();
controllermr.setview(vpanelmr);
controllermr.setmodel(modelmr);
```

and also there will be some modifications in controller class for the above design. for example i must change constructor of controller class

Thank you very much for your effort.

Answer (score -1):

MVC is used when you want to separate the Controller, Model and View from each other so that one will be (more or less) interchangable at a future stage, the way you are doing this now means there cannot be a View or a Model without the Controller, I would advise you to create them all separate from each other and pass references instead while still keeping the MVC-pattern

Comment: Actually they are seperate, but in the first design a controller directly connects to one model and view, so another View does not use this controller directly, only another view can use this view as a panel.